# iPhone: [super viewDidUnload] calling order

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I would like to know if there is any difference between calling [super viewDidUnload] before realeasing properties or after it.

Thank you!

```
  self.webView = nil;
  self.fullText = nil;
  [super viewDidUnload];
```

or

```
  [super viewDidUnload];
  self.webView = nil;
  self.fullText = nil;
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148450/viewdidload-unload-messages-to-super

Comment: possible duplicate of [`[super viewDidLoad]` convention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844195/super-viewdidload-convention)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This depends on what the superclass does in `viewDidUnload`. If it's just a standard `UIViewController`, either will do because `-[UIViewController viewDidUnload]` does nothing.

Comment: what about the other case - i.e. if `[super viewDidUnload]` is not a standard `UIViewController` and does something in `viewDidUnload`?

Comment: @delirus: For methods that "clean up", the super's implementation is usually called after. Similarly, methods that "initialize" should call super first.

Answer (score 10):

I never thought it mattered, but we just found a bug where the app crashed calling it first.  The trend at my office has been to call it last, but the Apple template puts it first.

You can do what you want, but I will always call it last from now on.

Comment: Interestingly, if you drag outlets from IB to code behind, it inserts the nil settings *before* the super call...makes no sense given the templates and the position of the comments.

Comment: Experienced the same as @ZaBlanc. Crash!

Comment: Though the template puts it first, I always put it last, as a safety feature, just in case super unloads something that may muck-up the program.

Answer (score 6):

This question is not fully answered. (And it's first hit when I google on this topic, so a complete answer would be useful to me and others.)

If the superclass DOES something in viewDidUnload, then what is the correct order for calling it in your class's viewDidUnload: before or after releasing properties?

For the record, it seems the consensus is to call the super method LAST:

`-(void)viewDidUnload {

    self.some_property = nil;

    [super viewDidUnload];

}`

Answer (score 2):

This only matters if the superclass of your view actually does something in `viewDidLoad`.  The default `UIViewController` doesn't do anything in `viewDidLoad` so if your view is a standard `UIViewController` then you can put `[super viewDidLoad]` anywhere in the `viewDidLoad` method.  However, if `super` does something in `viewDidLoad`, then it does matter where you put `[super viewDidLoad]`.

Comment: he asks about [super viewDidUnload] not viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 2):

This is just like the dealloc method.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [array release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

So I think we should call `[super viewDidUnload]` last.