# super viewDidUnload in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In the function viewDidUnload it is initially empty. However, I'm following a tutorial where at the end of the function they write [super viewDidUnload]. I noticed that in the dealloc function, [super dealloc] is automatically written at the end. Why isn't it automatically written at the end of viewDidUnload? Does it make a difference? What does it do?

Also, is this a Cocoa question, or an Objective-C question?

Comment: Cocoa is apple's framework written in Objective-C. Objective-C is the programming language, and Cocoa is the framework of classes Apple provides. Similar to PHP and CakePHP, or Ruby and Rails.

Comment: Yeah.. can we get this post renamed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This link may help: [iPhone: [super viewDidUnload] calling order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365440/iphone-super-viewdidunload-calling-order)

Basically, if the superclass is just `UIViewController`, `[UIViewController viewDidUnload]` does nothing, so that's why it's not automatically added.

Answer (score 0):

Call it at the end of the function.

I've had a lot of miscellaneous errors when i called at the beginning.  I found a lot of places on the web discuss the topic, some say beginning, some say at the end.  Before i researched, i figured it should be called at the end due to similar patterns of the structure and nature of the language (such as how touch events are handled).

My logic suggests that if i'm going to call the super, or parent of an object in question, i have to also think that the parent or super wouldn't know of the existence of the child object in its default implementation, and who knows what it might do.  So when over-riding this method it would be logical to think that when setting outlets and properties to nil, that the super's unload method might do something like unload the view in a view controller while those outlets still exist.

Due to all the questions and answers i found, there is no clear cut solution.  Apple doesn't give the immediate answer, but they provide an understanding of how the loading and unloading of views occurs.  I quit looking for examples on this one and i'm sticking to the logic behind the call to super at the end of this function.

What i wouldn't do is assume I can guess what code is being run in private API's and that anyone other than an apple doc or an apple developer will have the right answer.  nevertheless, this is my suggestion based on what i've experienced, perhaps the correct answer is that it should be either/or depending on what your doing in the method.  Open to more suggestions.