# should I write [super viewDidLoad]?

Tags: viewdidload, viewdidunload

I'm writing a navigation based app. (it has modal segues too)
I'm not sure if I should keep `[super viewDidLoad];` call or not. should I write code after this line of code or before it? how about `[super viewDidUnload];` and similars?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I always have to call \[super viewDidLoad\] in the -viewDidLoad method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824695/do-i-always-have-to-call-super-viewdidload-in-the-viewdidload-method), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844195/super-viewdidload-convention?lq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730345/do-i-need-to-call-super-viewdidunload?lq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708710/iphone-viewdidload?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to; according to the documentation, it's a stub function, so it doesn't do anything useful in non-subclasses.

---

Moral: always read the docs.

Comment: Ah, but the docs _also_ say that you should call it. See Paul Tomblin's and Steven Fisher's concerns at the duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824695/do-i-always-have-to-call-super-viewdidload-in-the-viewdidload-method

Comment: Well, I remember when I read them last time, therewas something exceptional in the docs and *this* was it, indeed. Maybe the documentation has been changed since then.