# Call super before or after setting up view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
//..do stuff..
}
```

or

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
//do stuff
    [super viewDidLoad];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [\[super viewDidLoad\] convention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844195/super-viewdidload-convention)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, if you're setting things up (e.g. `init`), super should go first.  If you're taking things down (e.g. `dealloc`), super should go last.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //..do stuff..
}
```

First of all let the super view controller do its initiation and then make yours.

2 reasons:

- You might depend on that initialization
- You might want to override super view controller's initialization

Once I had to deal with a bug of one of the developers in my team and eventually the bug was caused exactly by this - the `[super viewDidLoad];` was the last line in the `viewDidLoad` method...