# View Controller not Displaying

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, object, uiviewcontroller

I'm working on a baseball game app that contains multiple Modal View Controllers.  However, when I make the modal transition from "BasicGameSetupViewController" to "BasicViewController", the transition happens (because I have NSLog statements within my ViewDidLoad method in the BasicViewController), but the actual view does not update.  Here is the method where I transition to the BasicViewController (this code is in BasicGameSetupViewController):

```
- (IBAction)pressedBeginPlay:(id)sender {
    numOfInnings = [selectInnings selectedSegmentIndex];
    numOfInnings = numOfInnings + 1;
    row = [teamSelector selectedRowInComponent:0];
    visitor = [teams objectAtIndex:row];
    row = [teamSelector selectedRowInComponent:1];
    home = [teams objectAtIndex:row];
    NSLog(@"%@", visitor);
    NSLog(@"%@", home);
    if([awaySelect selectedSegmentIndex] == 0)
    {
        awayPlayer = @"Human";
    }
    else
    {
        awayPlayer = @"CPU";
    }
    if([homeSelect selectedSegmentIndex] == 0)
    {
        homePlayer = @"Human";
    }
    else
    {
        homePlayer = @"CPU";
    }
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"startBeginnerToBasic" sender:self];
}
```

(This block also has a "prepareForSegue" method)
And here is the viewDidLoad method in BasicViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    NSLog(@"Made it to basic View controller");
    homeLineup = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:9];
    visitorLineup = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:9];
    batter = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:22];
    homePitcher = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:22];
    awayPitcher = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:22];
    pitcher = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:22];
    homeAlreadyPitched = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:5];
    awayAlreadyPitched = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
    NSLog(@"arrays initialized");
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setUpTeams];
    [self checkForComputer];
    [self newBatter];
    [self atBat];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

I'm completely stumped as to why my view isn't showing.  The NSLog statements that are in the ViewDidLoad code block above show up, but the I can't get the view to show.  Does anyone have any ideas?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What were you expecting to see and what are you actually seeing?

Comment: This is not the answer you want but here is and advice:  
You should usually call [super viewDidLoad] as early as possible. Otherwise, the superclass may interfere with your own implementation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033668/does-it-make-a-difference-where-to-put-super-viewdidload-in-my-uiviewcontrolle

Comment: @MoisesCardenas, I did have the [super viewDidLoad] at the top of the [viewDidLoad] method, but it was still doing the same thing...

Comment: @LuisCien, I'm expecting to see the view for the BasicViewController (which I created in the storyboard), but I'm seeing the BasicGameSetupViewController that I designed in the storyboard.  I originally thought it was locking up, but I put NSLog statements in the BasicViewController that are displaying, so it's definitely getting to the BasicViewController