# Viewcontroller viewDidLoad method

Tags: objective-c, viewcontroller

Where `"[super viewDidLoad];"` should  be declared in viewDidLoad method ??

Will it make any difference if we have the `[super viewDidLoad];`  at the end of the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy answer - before your own methods to let application do all initialization work.

Read this answer for more info:
[`[super viewDidLoad]` convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844195/super-viewdidload-convention)