# Why do we use [super viewDidLoad] in every viewDidLoad method?   

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, viewcontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I always have to call [super viewDidLoad] in the -viewDidLoad method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824695/do-i-always-have-to-call-super-viewdidload-in-the-viewdidload-method)

Why is the super class' `viewDidLoad` method called in every `viewDidLoad`? What work will it do? Is it compulsory?

Answer (score 3):

It is not compulsory, but it is good design practice. It doesn't affect direct subclasses of the UIKit classes, but if you subclass a custom class, you'll need it. All it does is call the viewDidLoad of it's superclass to perform it's configuration.