# Why the call to super is the last thing on this method and not the first thing?

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, ipados

I am learning Swift as I go.

I found functions like this `viewDidLoad()` and many others are sometimes written like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

and sometimes written like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

I mean with the call to `super.viewDidLoad()` as the first thing or as the last thing inside the function?

What difference it makes to the program itself?

Comment: This should help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40151723/why-when-do-we-have-to-call-super-viewdidload

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906704/when-should-i-call-super.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621495-viewdidload) don't say that you need to call `super`. Contrast that to e.g. `viewWillAppear(_:)`, whose [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear) state:

> If you override this method, you must call `super` at some point in your implementation.

Thus, calling `super` is only needed if you have a custom subclass of `UIViewController`, let's call it `BaseViewController`, which does something in `viewDidLoad()`.

When you then inherit from `BaseViewController`, you probably need to call `super` to do the work of `BaseViewController`. Depending on the nature of it, you'd need to do it at the beginning, somewhere in the middle, or at the end of your subclass's `viewDidLoad()`. This is up to this `BaseViewController` to document it properly.

Here's a contrived example:

```swift
class ColorfulViewController: UIViewController {
    /// Defines background color of view. Override in subclass.
    var shinyColor: UIColor = .red

    /// Sets the background color. Make sure to call `super` in subclass.
    func viewDidLoad() {
        backgroundColor = shinyColor
    }
}

class PinkViewController: ColorfulViewController {
    override var shinyColor: UIColor = .systemPink

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() // This one doesn't matter where it goes.
        // Additional work.
    }
}
```

Another contrived example where you'd want to call `super` at the end:

```swift
class CountingViewController: UIViewController {
    var count: Int = 0

    /// Counts the subviews. When subclassing, make sure to call `super` *after*
    /// view is fully configured.
    func viewDidLoad() {
        count = view.subviews.count
    }
}

class FooViewController: CountingViewController {
    override var shinyColor: UIColor = .systemPink

    func viewDidLoad() {
        // Additional work.
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Usually for `viewDidLoad()` you would put the super call at the beggining of the method, because there is not really a reason to not do so.

You would have to understand the concept of `super` calls to understand it better.
`super.someFunction()` calls a function of the super class. In our case, your custom View Controller's class, let's say `MyViewController` is `UIViewController`, which is where `viewDidLoad()` is originally defined. In this case where you **override** the method, you should call the `super` call to make sure nothing is left behind. Note that in `viewDidLoad()` specifically it is not mandatory to call the super from `UIViewController`, although it is advised as a defensive call. Usually the documentation mention it is required or not.

If you had another custom view controller, let's say `MySecondViewController` which subclassed from `MyViewController`, and you wanted to perform some actions before the `viewDidLoad()` from `MyViewController` took place, you can position the `super.viewDidLoad()` of `MySecondViewController` at the end of the functions, or where you desire, like so:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        doSomething()
    }
}

class MySecondViewController: MyViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Do something else before doSomething() is called by the superclass
        doSomethingElse()
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: fantastic explanation. THANKS.

Comment: The claims "there is not really a reason to not do so" and "you must call the super call to make sure nothing is left behind" are just not true. The docs tell you when it is mandatory. IMO it's rather defensive to call `super` just because you're overriding a method. In fact, many times you don't want `super`'s behavior to kick in when overriding.