# remove super.viewDidLoad() from viewDidLoad() function

Tags: ios, swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(" viewDidLoad")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

there is any problem if  super.viewDidLoad() from above function

Comment: Also Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844195/super-viewdidload-convention https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824695/do-i-always-have-to-call-super-viewdidload-in-the-viewdidload-method

Comment: See as per the apple doc. you should call super.viewDidLoad method because it may do some initial setup for your parent/super class as your customVC class is inherited from VC class. If you don't do this also it works fine but in some cases it may show unpredictable behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it takes away the opportunity of the `super` to do anything in `viewDidLoad()`.

If the `super` doesn't do anything (which may be the case if you are subclassing `UIViewController` directly), then you may not see any immediate difference. But if you were to subclass the class you just wrote and not call the `super`, for example, then your print would not be called.

See more: [Do I always have to call [super viewDidLoad] in the -viewDidLoad method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824695/do-i-always-have-to-call-super-viewdidload-in-the-viewdidload-method)

Answer (score 0):

For a VC inheriting from `UIViewController`, not calling `super.viewDidLoad` makes no difference.

However, when you have a VC that inherits from a class that actually does something in its `viewDidLoad` *will* make a difference.

---

#### Example 1

I once made a board game and I had a `GameViewController` that shows the game screen for a two player game. `GameViewController.viewDidLoad` does some setup of the game board view and the game model and so on. Then one day I decided to write an AI for the game so that people can play even when they are alone. The game with the AI is a little different from a two player game, so I made a `AIGameViewController`, which inherits `GameViewController`.

In `AIGameViewController`, I must call `super.viewDidLoad`, or else I have to copy and paste the code in `GameViewController.viewDidLoad`.

---

#### Example 2

There is a library called "Eureka" that allows you to create forms for users to fill in. To use it, you create a new VC that inherits from `FormViewController`, and then you can start to add rows to the form in `viewDidLoad`. It is required to call `super.viewDidLoad` here because `FormViewController` will, among other things, set up a table view to display the form. Without the table view, your form will not be displayed.